# High System Usage : <40%

Tags: windows, windows-11

Laptop Specs : Lenovo IdeaPad Slim 3
i3 10th gen
8GB DDR4 RAM
512 Nvme

My PC's system is eating high percentage of the CPA.
Sometimes even 55%+
This is running latest Win 11.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Your screenshot indicates a user ram process is taking 72% of your CPU utilization. Wouldn’t fully trust that there are two separate System processes running. If you disable your user ram processes accept for those absolutely required does that have an impact on how the system runs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @harrymc said the issue was in the Postman. Here are the steps that I took to solve the issue.

1. Go to the help:

   [image: Help Navigation]
2. Disable the Hardware Acceleration (Mine was already turned off right away):

   [image: Disable Acceleration]

Answer (score 5):

Seems like you came up against
[postman.exe](https://www.postman.com/)
bug
[CPU usage way too high #7370](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/7370):

> CPU usage is through the roof when idle. Was doing nothing and left it in the background for a couple hours, it spawned 3 more individual processes and did this. Note I only opened the app once.

A comment in this post was :

> As soon as I made the first request in postman my CPU would be over 50% constantly. Disabling hardware acceleration fixed the problem straight away.

I suggest then to disable hardware acceleration in Postman.
As I'm not using this product, I can't give exact instructions
on how to do that.

If you don't really need Postman, you could just uninstall it.

Comment: Thanks @harrymc. Did as you said, and the issue is now fixed. Thanks for the assist, Keep up good work