# System Usage 100% - All apps are stucking

Tags: windows, windows-11

I am getting high system CPU usage. I first thought that it was due to the Postman bug.
Posted here: [High System Usage : <40%](https://superuser.com/questions/1754167/high-system-usage-40)

After following those steps, it becomes sometimes better, but again it shows high system usage. I event uninstalled the Postman, but no luck. My PC is screaming.

Any new solutions for this?

Comment: This could be anything but in general I recommand uninstalling any antivirus software and use Windows Defender instead. I have a computer service business and in 80% of all slow PCs this is the solution. Also you can take a look into resource manager to see what is consuming CPU.

Comment: @somega I only have Defender,  In the processes it shows System is using more that 70%

Comment: You could reinstall Windows.

Comment: Run Hardware Diagnostics before reinstalling the operating system to check hardware.

Comment: Any chance you still use a HDD? High CPU could also be the result of high IOWAIT.

Comment: You have an existing question. It should be improved and updated until it can be answered. What you should not do is post a new post for what is the same question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [High System Usage : <40%](https://superuser.com/questions/1754167/high-system-usage-40)

Comment: @music2myear, No mate. That is my first question, still trying to figure it out.